# Find a valid IAM role for successful and failed delivery of AWS SNS

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Hi i am trying to create a SNS topic but i am getting error attached screen shot for reference. 
My requirement is when ever message published to SNS topic i have to access the message and it's entire events through lambda function but while creating a topic itself i am getting the error.

[image]

Could some one kindly help me to understand and resolve above issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an IAM role which needs to have appropriate permissions to perform write actions to CloudWatch Logs.

Your error tells you that you haven't selected an IAM role that should be used for your SNS topic. Simply tick "Create new service role" and that will solve your issue by creating new IAM role which will automatically be used for your deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If in case you are not allowed to create new service role by clicking on "create new service role" option, you can create it separately and use the ARN of the service role.

Use this CFT:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Service role",
    "Resources": {
        "SNSSuccessFailureLogDeliveryRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
                            },
                            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "RoleName": "SNSSuccessFailureServiceRole"
                
            }
        },
        "SNSSuccessFailureServiceRolePolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "PolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": [
                                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                                "logs:PutMetricFilter",
                                "logs:PutRetentionPolicy"
                            ],
                            "Resource": [
                                "*"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Roles": [
                    "SNSSuccessFailureServiceRole"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```